# Hibernate: Initialize all children with a single join statement in HQL / QueryDSL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, querydsl

We're using QueryDSL right now for our database queries but I think the question is more generally hibernate related..

I'm wondering: Does HQL put the entities I query for into the hibernate context/cache so that they can be accessed from there? I'm thinking, if I run a big `leftjoin` for an entity, explicitly collecting all child relations, I should be able to save on the lazy loadings if I can just tell hibernate to use that information when mapping the result to my entity object. I just can't figure out how..

**Example:** 
A has Bs and B has Cs. Now if I build my query to `fetch all` for a certain A and also join it with Bs and Cs (query DSL implemenentation):

```
List<A> as = query.from(QA.a).leftJoin(QA.a.b,QB.b).leftJoin(QB.b.c,QC.c).where(a.id.eq("1)).fetchAll();
```

I will get a nice SQL statement that says

```
select... from A inner join B ... inner join C ... where ...
```

So the result should be sufficient for hibernate to initialize

```
as.get(index).getBs()
as.get(index).getBs().get(index).getCs()
```

but it won't do it, instead it will run queries to

```
select ...  from B where B.aId = ??
```

Is it possible at all to reduce these lazy loadings by initializing an entity with all children with one join or am I hoping for too much?

If I load all the data with a join, will hibernate have them in its cache and will it access that cache for those lazy loadings or will it poll the database? Do I get a say in that or is it completely out of my hands?

Thanks @ all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot to mention this in my post. I did try using `fetch` but with no success. Turns out the solution is to use

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

at the entity property.

Comment: Did you try leftJoin / fetch without the alias arguments?

Comment: No, didn't try that.. If I don't use aliases, source code and query will bloat up... But I'll give it a try. I am using innerJoin and leftJoin depending on the relationship.

Answer (score 4):

In a HQL query, you need to use the `fetch` keyword to do that:

```
select a from A a left join fetch a.cs b left join fetch b.cs where ...
```

This is well explained in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

I've never used QueryDSL, but according to [its documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.6.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/jpa/JPQLQuery.html#fetch%28%29), you just need to call the fetch() method after each join to add this fetch keyword:

```
query.from(QA.a).leftJoin(QA.a.b,QB.b).fetch().leftJoin(QB.b.c,QC.c).fetch().where...
```